# Previous Step function not working properly

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-hooks, bubble-sort

I have a function called "handleStep" that iterates through each step in bubble sort, and it should update the history such that I can use "handleGoBack" to return to any previous states. I know there is some problem with the history when I update the passIndex but I don't know what to do. Please help me!

```
const [numbers, setNumbers] = useState([5, 2, 9, 1, 8]);
    const [passIndex, setPassIndex] = useState(0);
    const [swapIndex, setSwapIndex] = useState(0);
    const [swapDetails, setSwapDetails] = useState([]);
    const [history, setHistory] = useState([{ numbers: [...numbers], swapDetails: [] },]);

    const handleGoBack = () => {

        if (passIndex === 0 && swapIndex === 0) {
            return; // Already at the initial step
        }

        let previousSwap = swapIndex - 1;
        if (previousSwap < 0) {
            previousSwap = numbers.length-1;
            setPassIndex(passIndex - 1);
        }
        const previousHistory = history.slice(0, history.length - 1);
        const previousStep = previousHistory[previousHistory.length - 1];

        setNumbers([...previousStep.numbers]);
        setSwapIndex(previousSwap);
        setSwapDetails(swapDetails.slice(0, swapDetails.length - 1));
        setHistory(previousHistory);

};

const handleStep = () => {

        // Return if already sorted
        if (isSorted(numbers) || passIndex >= numbers.length) {
            return;
        }

        // Updates if the next number is less than the current number at swapIndex
        if (numbers[swapIndex] > numbers[swapIndex + 1]) {
            [numbers[swapIndex], numbers[swapIndex + 1]] = [
                numbers[swapIndex + 1],
                numbers[swapIndex],
            ];
            swapDetails.push(
                `${numbers[swapIndex]} swaps with ${numbers[swapIndex + 1]}`
            );

        }
        else {
            swapDetails.push('No swap made');
        }

        const updatedHistory = [...history, { numbers: numbers, swapDetails: swapDetails }];
        setHistory(updatedHistory);

        // Return if swapIndex+1 has reached the final length of numbers minus passIndex
        if (swapIndex + 1 === numbers.length - passIndex) {
            setSwapIndex(0);
            setPassIndex(passIndex + 1);
            setSwapDetails([]);
            return;
        }

        // Update swapIndex if it has not reached the final length of numbers minus passIndex
        setSwapIndex(swapIndex + 1);
};


const isSorted = (arr) => {
        for (let i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
            if (arr[i] > arr[i + 1]) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
};
```

I tried updating the history when I update the passIndex, but I don't really know.